# How to get which button is which in a Yes/No/Cancel dialog using UI Automation?

Tags: c#, ui-automation

In the proprietary third-party application my program has to communicate with, there is a situation where an operation I have to invoke displays a system dialog with Yes/No/Cancel buttons. I now need to push the "Yes" button. There is no vendor-side function to tell the application to do the operation that starts when I push "Yes", so I have to use UI automation.

Where I am stuck with is the localization of the Windows standard dialogs. The caption of the "Yes" button is different depending on the language Windows is used in, and the order might also be different in languages which are written from right to left.
Since we are currently only using German and English versions of Windows where this program is used, I currently just click the first element in the subtree of the window that supports the `InvokePattern` which is always "Yes" in these language versions, and the program is used only in-house. But I don't like this, I want a robust way to determine which button is which. Is this possible with UI automation?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to use the [AutomationID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684017(v=vs.85).aspx) property to uniquely identify a button.   Don't use the [Runtime ID](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winuiautomation/2016/07/07/dont-use-the-uia-runtimeid-property-in-your-find-condition/), as that's not guaranteed to be unique across invocations.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are only targeting English and German, you can just look for a control with a caption/text property of "Yes" (for English). In German environments, look for the German equivalent of *yes* which you should know at coding-time.

Answer (score 0):

This is best practice I used in privious project for UI automation in localized software:

1. Use AutomationId(UIA)/ControlId(MSAA) if possible.
2. Locate corresponding resource file and load string from it. Then search it in UI. Hard code localized string in test code is bad idea. You can't grantee that

   1. text is translated correctly even for Windows
   2. text is already translated in specific language when you expand your scope.
   3. text is translated consistently everywhere.
3. Simulate keyboard {tab} and {space} to click a button.
4. Use control sequence as you're currently doing, but nobody can grantee that button with index 0 is in the leftmost.
5. Use absolute pixel/position. Sometimes button are drawn as picture.